# Firefox flatpak does not work with Slack flatpack link

Tags: xfce, browser, url, flatpak

How does Slack flatpak find the application for a URL?

I have xfce4 on Debian Linux.

I noticed that Libre Office is smart enough to open Flatpak Firefox so how does slack find the default browser (and only browser in this case)?

If I install konqueror via apt-get, then konqueror is used with the link in slack. Without a browser installed by dpkg, I get the message under a handbag:

> No Apps Available ... You can find more applications in Software

Here are the xdg-settings, which I presume Slack is not using.

```
$ xdg-settings check default-web-browser org.mozilla.firefox.desktop
yes
```